# Get annotation for enum type

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, enums

How can I get SemanticId annotation value?:

```
@SemanticId("Something")
public enum SomeEnum {
    FIRST("First"),
    SECOND("Second")
}
```

Comment: `SomeEnum.class.getAnnotation(SemanticId.class).value()`.

Answer (score 0):

For Java:

```
    SomeEnum.class
              .getAnnotation(SemanticId.class)
              .value()
```

For Kotlin:

```
SomeEnum.annotations
                .filterIsInstance(SemanticId::class.java)
                .map { it.value }
                .firstOrNull()
```

Comment: Both snippets are incorrect: the first one doesn't need `value()`, the second one doesn't invoke the `::class` operator to obtain `KClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets in [Dmytro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69206778/10117056) are incorrect.

First of all, `SemanticId` must have annotation retention `RUNTIME` otherwise it won't be available through reflection.

There are three ways to obtain its instance with reflection:

Java Reflection:

```java
SemanticId myId = SomeEnum.class.getAnnotation(SemanticId.class);
```

Java Reflection used in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val myId = SomeEnum::class.java.getAnnotation(SemanticId::class.java)
```

Kotlin Reflection which requires additional dependency on `kotlin-reflect.jar` (explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#jvm-dependency)):

```kotlin
val myId = SomeEnum::class.findAnnotation<SemanticId>()
```